# CakePHP : Add “List-Unsubscribe” in email header using Email component

Tags: php, email, cakephp

I am usign cakephp 2.x and using Email components to send email.

I am trying to add List-Unsubscribe at headers.

```
$this->Email->headers = [
'List-Unsubscribe'=>'<mailto:'.$email_from.'?subject=Remove from Mailing List>, <'.$SITEURL.'unsubscribe?em='.$email_to.'>',
'List-Unsubscribe-Post'=>'List-Unsubscribe=One-Click' 
];
```

Now in email source its showing in X-header.

```
X-List-Unsubscribe: <mailto:clients@example.com?subject=Remove from Mailing List>, <http://example.com/unsubscribe?em=xyz@example.com>
X-List-Unsubscribe-Post: List-Unsubscribe=One-Click
```

But it's not showing Unsubscribe link with From.

I need List-Unsubscribe in message header to avoid spam email.

When i try to use `$this->Email->additionalParams`  its not showing List-Unsubscribe in email header.

Here is code that i am using

```
$send_from = $email_from_name . "<" . $email_from . ">";
$this->Email->sendAs = 'both'; // text / html / both
$this->Email->from = $send_from; 
$this->Email->replyTo = $email_from;
$this->Email->return = $email_from; 
$this->Email->to = $email_to;
$this->Email->delivery = 'smtp';
$this->Email->smtpOptions = ['host'=>$imap_server,'port'=>587,'username'=>$email,'password'=>$password];
$this->Email->subject = $subject;

$this->Email->headers = [
'List-Unsubscribe'=>'<mailto:'.$email_from.'?subject=Remove from Mailing List>, <'.SITEURL.'unsubscribe?em='.$email_to.'>',
'List-Unsubscribe-Post'=>'List-Unsubscribe=One-Click' ];
$this->Email->textMessage = $this->_html_to_text($content);
//$this->Email->delivery = 'debug';
$this->Email->send($content);
```

Answer (score 1):

The email component doesn't support custom non X-prefixed headers, if you need that you'll have to use `CakeEmail`, which by default doesn't prefix headers, and requires you to explicitly pass prefixed headers in case required.

Given that [**the email component is long deprecated**](https://book.cakephp.org/2/en/appendices/2-0-migration-guide.html#emailcomponent), ever since the first release of CakePHP 2 to be specific, now is probably a good time for you to finally drop it.

Quick and dirty example:

```php
App::uses('CakeEmail', 'Network/Email');

// The transport/connection configuration should probably better be moved into a config file
$Email = new CakeEmail(array(
    'transport' => 'Smtp',
    'host' => $imap_server,
    'port' => 587,
    'username' => $email,
    'password' => $password
));
$Email
    ->emailFormat('both')
    ->template('subscribe')
    ->from($send_from)
    ->replyTo($email_from)
    ->returnPath($email_from)
    ->to($email_to)
    ->subject($subject)
    ->addHeaders(array(
        'List-Unsubscribe' =>
            '<mailto:' . $email_from . '?subject=Remove from Mailing List>, ' .
            '<' . $SITEURL . 'unsubscribe?em=' . $email_to . '>',
        'List-Unsubscribe-Post' => 'List-Unsubscribe=One-Click'
    ))
    ->send($content);
```

This would require two templates, one for HTML in `app/View/Emails/html/subscribe.ctp`:

```php
<?php
// $content contains the data passed to the `send()` method, wrapped to max 998 chars per line
echo $content;
```

and one for text in `app/View/Emails/text/subscribe.ctp`, requiring you to move the HTML to text conversion into the template. You should probably [**make it a helper**](https://book.cakephp.org/2/en/views/helpers.html#creating-helpers), the following should just illustrate the principle:

```php
<?php
echo _html_to_text($content);
```

See also

- **[Cookbook > Core Libraries > Utilities > CakeEmail > Configuration](https://book.cakephp.org/2/en/core-utility-libraries/email.html#configuration)**
- **[Cookbook > Core Libraries > Utilities > CakeEmail > Sending templated emails](https://book.cakephp.org/2/en/core-utility-libraries/email.html#sending-templated-emails)**

Comment: I will try to replace with CakeMail but still i edited Email component  then after email source showing 

List-Unsubscribe: <mailto:clients@example.com?subject=Remove from Mailing List>, <https://example.com/unsubscribe?em=abc@example.com>  but still Unsubscribe link is not showing.

Comment: @YogeshSaroya That sounds like a new problem/question then, possibly not even CakePHP related. If you can now produce the correct headers, you should maybe open a new question and elaborate on your target environment that is supposed to evaluate the headers (and how it would do so), the exact E-Mail headers that are being generated, and investigate the differences to a working E-Mail with these unsubscribe headers.